# How to get schema of a table if I have the oid (Postgres 9.5.1)?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to get the schema of a table if I have the oid in Postgres 9.5.1. I tried using `information_schema` but can't figure out which table I use to join with the `oid`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to join [`pg_namespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-namespace.html) to [`pg_class`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html)

```
select nsp.nspname as schema_name, tbl.relname as table_name
from pg_namespace nsp
  join pg_class tbl on nsp.oid = tbl.relnamespace
where tbl.oid = 42;
```